# Change background color and font features in navbarPage elements

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know hot to change the default white background of a navbar Page menu and also the font type and color of all its elements in a shiny dashboard.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    navbarPage("Title",
               navbarMenu("More",
                          tabPanel("Table"

                          ),
                          tabPanel("About"

                          )
               )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CSS to your app: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

For the text  (from [How to specify font attributes for all elements on an html web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942254/how-to-specify-font-attributes-for-all-elements-on-an-html-web-page)):

```
* {
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: black;
}
```

For the background color:

```
.content-wrapper, .right-side {
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

EDIT: For Navbar try ([Change background colour of navbarPage menubar in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305668/change-background-colour-of-navbarpage-menubar-in-r-shiny)):

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #b1b1b3 !important;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry I mean the background color of the navbarapage menu only not the whole app

Comment: thanks that works .for the color text ? I need to put color: in the first chunk that you posted?

Comment: it changed everything except of the navbar color text

Comment: The * means you are choosing the font size and color for ALL the text in the page.  To change the navbar text color, you need to try and target that element.  One hint that might help with this - start the app, right click the element you are interested and "Inspect".   This should show the code behind the scenes that can help you change the look of the page.   This link might have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420076/r-shiny-change-color-of-text-in-navbarpage/43421166