# Apply background color for all page, including navigation bar in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

On the code bellow I tried to stablish a background color in all my Shiny UI page but I couldnt do this for the Navigation Bar:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

    setBackgroundColor(
        color = c("#F7FBFF", "#2171B5"),
        gradient = "linear",
        direction = c("bottom","left")
    ),

titlePanel("Titulo"),

navbarPage( 

title = h1('Métodos'),
    tabPanel(h1('Painel Geral')),
                 tabPanel(h1('Painel Geral')),
                          tabPanel(h1('Painel Geral')),
                                   tabPanel(h1('Painel Geral'))))


server <- function(input, output) {


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see the navbar still gray. How can I change for the entire page?

Also how can I change it using the .css file?

I tried all the `divs` but didnt work.

Any help?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make the navbar the same color gradient as the whole page? To just change the color of the navbar you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420076/r-shiny-change-color-of-text-in-navbarpage/43421166)

Comment: @astrofunkswag thanks for your time. Actually what I want is the same color gradient thw whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)

css <- "
.navbar-default {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(css)),
  setBackgroundColor(
    color = c("#F7FBFF", "#2171B5"),
    gradient = "linear",
    direction = c("bottom","left")
  ),
  ......
```

If you don't want to use `shinyWidgets::setBackgroundColor`, use this css:

```
css <- "
body {
  min-height: 100%; 
  width:100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
  position: absolute; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom left, #F7FBFF, #2171B5) fixed;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom left, #F7FBFF, #2171B5) fixed;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom left, #F7FBFF, #2171B5) fixed;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom left, #F7FBFF, #2171B5) fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #F7FBFF, #2171B5) fixed;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}
"
```

Comment: many thanks for your time! You answered my question! Could you give me another help? How can I do this without using the `setBackgroundColor`? Just using css file?

Comment: Thanks! I have no words.